# Replace value in string

Tags: linux, bash

I have text file with ~70k lines like this:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/2013/04/04/file.pdf
```

and I need to convert it to:

```
dir4/dir5/2013/04/4/file.pdf
```

It's important that the leading `0` in 6th place is removed, values in this place go from 1 to 31. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` :

```
sed -E 's@(/[^/]*){3}(/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/)0?([0-9]+.*)@dir4/dir5\2\3@' your_file
```

We match the three dirs in a first group that will be disregarded (we'd be using a non-capturing group if `sed` supported it), then the year and month in a second group, then optionnaly the leading 0 of the day, then the rest of the day and the filename in a third group. The replacement pattern just specifies the new path root then refers to the second and third groups. I'm using `@` as a delimiter to avoid having to espace all the `/` in the pattern and replacement pattern, any character that isn't found in them would work as well.

[Try it online !](https://ideone.com/aV0W1W)